# OnItemSelectedListener не может быть преобразован в контекст

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

IDE выдает ошибку "Error:(23, 30) error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Context".
Что значит "OnItemSelectedListener не может быть преобразован в контекст?".
Все делаю по образцу, только в образце всплывающие сообщения в зависимости от выбора позиции. А мне надо наполнение второго spinner в зависимости от выбранной позиции.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinnerBase = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.baseSpinner);
    spinnerBase.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (position == 1){
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                        (this, R.array.forPress, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                Spinner spinnerSecond=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);
                spinnerSecond.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else
```

IDE выдает ошибку на "this" в строке "createFromResource
                            (this, R.array.forPress, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)".
Документацию читал https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource(android.content.Context, int, int). Буду очень признателен за объяснение, что я делаю не так. И вдвойне признателен за пример варианта решения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ключевое слово `this` используется для ссылки на текущий объект класса. Вы же используете его в анонимном классе. В вашем случае достаточно указать `MainActivity.this`

Comment: работает, спасибо